# "file_name.exe has stopped working"

Tags: c

This problem is from spoj. Please see [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/DIVFACT/) for question.
My logic is simple as you will see. If I change array sizes in dynamic form to static ones, the code executes and asks for integers and keeps executing like indefinitely whilst it should run for the number of test cases. However if I have kept dynamic, I keep getting this persistent error: file_name.exe has stopped working.

Also plz comment on my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, count, k, tcs, j, l, m;
    scanf("%d", tcs);
    int fact[tcs];
    int arr[tcs];
    for (j = 0; j < tcs; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[j]);
    }

    int calc_fact(n) {
        if (n == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return n * calc_fact(n - 1);
    }

    j = 0;
    m = 0;
    while (m < tcs && j < tcs) {
        fact[m] = calc_fact(arr[j]);
        m++;
        j++;
    }

    m = 0;
    for (l = 0; l < tcs; l++) {
        i = 1;
        count = 0;
        while (i <= fact[m]) {
            if ((fact[m]) % i == 0)
                count++;
            i++;
        }
        m++;
        k = (count) % ((10 ^ 9) + 7);
        printf("\n%d", k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First visible bug, ignoring the return value of `scanf()`. Also, this code is completely unreadable. If you don't care about the formatting of your code you don't respect other programmers. Second bug, you are learning a OS specific thing that no one uses anymore, and you are not even using it in the code.

Comment: You also defined functions inside other functions, nested functions are not legal [tag:c].

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick one.

Comment: Undefined behaviour in `scanf("%d", tcs);`, should use `scanf("%d", &tcs);` instead.

Comment: @iharob Such a rookie mistake!! Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using C++, there are couple of things that you need to change in your code:

1. `scanf("%d", tcs);` should rather be `scanf("%d", &tcs);`  This mistake is the reason your program crashes, as `tcs` doesn't have the correct intended value.
2. The function `int calc_fact(n)` should be outside the main() function with the prototype `int calc_fact(int n)`.  Due to this mistake, your code won't compile in the first place (are you sure when you say that your code complies when the arrays are declared statically)?

Please see the modified code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>                    //You actually don't need it.

int calc_fact(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*calc_fact(n-1);
}

int main()
{
    int n, i, count, k, tcs, j, l, m;
    scanf("%d", &tcs);
    int fact[tcs];
    int arr[tcs];
    for(j=0; j<tcs; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[j]);
    }

    j=0;
    m=0;
    while(m<tcs && j<tcs)
    {
        fact[m]=calc_fact(arr[j]);
        m++;
        j++;
    }


    m=0;
    for(l=0; l<tcs; l++)
    {
        i=1;
        count=0;
        while(i<=fact[m])
        {
            if((fact[m])%i==0)
            count++;
            i++;
        }
    m++;
    k=(count)%((10^9)+7);
    printf("%d\n", k);            //and not printf("\n%d", k);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Working code [**here**](http://ideone.com/hxCzc3).

Comment: Thanks, @MahmoudAl-Qudsi, but I was more interested in finding out the reason of the downvote - any problem with the code or my approach, etc.?  I could have used a different logic, but then I wanted to make minimum changes to the OP's code.

Comment: Here comes the 2nd downvote.. again without mentioning any reason. :)